# DirectX 11 - Drawing multiple viewports RSSetViewports with an array of CD3D11_VIEWPORT

Tags: windows, winapi, directx, directx-11

I've set up my vertex shader and my pixel shader.
I then created a vector to represent my viewports (4 in total in this case):

```
std::vector<CD3D11_VIEWPORT> view_ports;
```

I've populated the vector and all 4 elements have the same default values:

```
view_port.Width = 400;
view_port.Height = 300;
view_port.MinDepth = 0;
view_port.MaxDepth = 1;
```

The only values that differ are the [TopLeftX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/ns-d3d11-d3d11_viewport) and [TopLeftY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/ns-d3d11-d3d11_viewport) since I want each view port in a different position.

Now if I call [RSSetViewports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11devicecontext-rssetviewports) and [DrawIndexed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11devicecontext-drawindexed) like below, it only draws one of the view ports why is that? **RSSetViewports** is supposed to accept multiple viewports based on its description.

```
pContext->RSSetViewports( view_ports.size(), view_ports.data() )
pContext->DrawIndexed( static_cast< UINT > ( std::size( indices ) ), 0u, 0u )
```

If I do it like this however it does work and draws all 4 viewports:

```
pContext->RSSetViewports( 1u, &view_ports[0] );
pContext->DrawIndexed( static_cast<UINT> ( std::size( indices ) ), 0u, 0u );
pContext->RSSetViewports( 1u, &view_ports[1] );
pContext->DrawIndexed( static_cast<UINT> ( std::size( indices ) ), 0u, 0u );
pContext->RSSetViewports( 1u, &view_ports[2] );
pContext->DrawIndexed( static_cast<UINT> ( std::size( indices ) ), 0u, 0u );
pContext->RSSetViewports( 1u, &view_ports[3] );
pContext->DrawIndexed( static_cast<UINT> ( std::size( indices ) ), 0u, 0u );
```

if you look at the arguments of [RSSetViewports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11devicecontext-rssetviewports)

```
void RSSetViewports(
  [in]           UINT                 NumViewports,
  [in, optional] const D3D11_VIEWPORT *pViewports
);
```

It does take an array of viewports, can't I just call it once with my vector like so?:

```
pContext->RSSetViewports( view_ports.size(), view_ports.data() )
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Do you use SV_ViewportArrayIndex semantic in a geometry shader? see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11devicecontext-rssetviewports#remarks

Comment: @SimonMourier I have not set up the geometry shader

Comment: *"if a geometry shader does not specify the semantic, Direct3D will use the first viewport in the array"*, so it's useless to send 4 viewports

Comment: @SimonMourier omg I missed that, thanks Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Simon Mourier's suggestion:

You need to use `SV_ViewportArrayIndex` semantic in a geometry shader.

According to the Doc:[ID3D11DeviceContext::RSSetViewports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11devicecontext-rssetviewports#remarks)

> Which viewport to use is determined by the SV_ViewportArrayIndex
> semantic output by a geometry shader; if a geometry shader does not
> specify the semantic, Direct3D will use the first viewport in the
> array.